# Bulk update MySQL table with data concatenated from another table

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update, trim, concatenation

This isn't WordPress specific, but it's worth noting that it's a WP db I'm working with...

I need to update the `posts` table value `post_title` for all entries with `post_type='appearance'`.  The current `post_title` begins with the desired name, but it ends with "appearance [some #]".  So, from "appearance" to the end needs to be removed, and it needs to be replaced with the `meta_value` from table `postmeta` where `meta_key = _place_id` and `post_id` is equal to the `ID` from the `posts` table.

For example: there's a post with ID `102` titled "John Doe appearance 102".  In the `postmeta` table, where `meta_key = _place_id` and `post_id = 102`, `meta_value = 108`.  Thus the final result would be that `post_title = John Doe 108`.

This is complicated beyond me, but I imagine a join is necessary.  And I figure two separate queries would make sense.  So, something similar to:

```
UPDATE posts

SET post_title = TRIM(TRAILING ' appearance %' FROM post_title)

WHERE post_type='appearance'
```

and

```
UPDATE posts

left join postmeta on
    posts.ID= postmeta.post_id
set
    posts.post_title = CONCAT(posts.post_title, " ", postmeta.meta_value WHERE postmeta.meta_key = '_place_id')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a single query by making use of `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`:

```
UPDATE posts p
LEFT JOIN postmeta pm
    ON p.ID = pm.post_id
SET p.post_title = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.post_title, 'appearance', 1), pm.meta_value)
WHERE pm.meta_key = '_place_id'
```

Taking `SUBSTRING_INDEX('John Doe appearance 102', 'appearance', 1)` would return everything *before* the occurrence of `appearance`, which is `John Doe` (with a space at the end).  Then, we can simply concatenate on the `meta_value`.

Comment: That looks great.  Sadly, I'm getting an error: `Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'SUBSTRING_INDEX'`

Comment: Thank you.  Beautiful.  One thing that was missing, but turned out fine, was specifying the post_type.